# How do I bind object property and send the data via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-framework-beans

I'm struggling with sending a data which contains object as a member property.

This is the domain class.

```
public class Timeline extends Post{
    String picture;
    User user;
    int like;
    ...
    (getters and setters)
}
```

And I've got the JSON data with this code already so I could get the data from 'obj' variable.

```
var obj;
$.ajax({
method: "GET",
dataType: "json",
url: serverRoot + "/json/auth/loginUser",
async: false
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    obj = data;
 });
```

And the returned data looks like this.

```
 "user" : {
         "userNo" : 1,
         "name" : "user01",
             ...
      }
```

The next JSON data is the data I'd like to send to a server.

```
{
  "no" : 23,
  "content" : "hihi",
  "createdData" : "2018-07-22",
  "picture" : null,
  "user" : {
     "userNo" : 1,
     "name" : "user01",
         ... **obj JSON data I got above**
  }
}
```

And this is the codes to send to a server.
(Here is the thing I've been stuck)

```
$("#sh-tl-post-btn").click(() => {
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '../../../json/timeline/add',
    data: {
      picture: $('#sh_tl_upload').val(),
      content: $('#sh_tl_post_write').val(),
      **user: [{"userNo":obj.userNo}]**
    },
  }).done(function() {
    console.log("inserted.");
    location.href = "timeline.html"
   });
});
```

The Mapper file looks like this.

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="Timeline">
    <choose>
        <when test="picture != ''">
            insert into TML(tmlno, uno, tmlpath)
            values(#{no}, #{userNo}, #{picture})
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            insert into TML(tmlno, uno)
            values(#{no}, #{userNo})
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
</insert>
```

I've been searching what to write on here instead of 
   **user: [{"userNo":obj.userNo}]** , this...

I've been trying

```
user : {"userNo" : obj.userNo}
user.userNo : obj.userNo
user.[0].userNo : obj.userNo
...
```

but the console keeps saying

```
    [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
     org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException:.....
```

this kind of errors.

Is there anyone could help me how to bind the nested object's property via ajax 
 JSON data? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `user: [{"userNo":obj.user.userNo}]` instead of `user: [{"userNo":obj.userNo}]`?

Comment: I've tried that. but it returns "Uncaught TypeError : Cannot read property 'userNo' of undefined" on chrome browser.

Comment: From the json structure you posted, if you want the value `1`, that is `obj.user.userNo`. Now, in what structure you should send it, I don't know.

Comment: Yes, I want to send the value **1**.  but the obj is 'User' class' JSON data, not a whole JSON data I posted. Sorry not clear enough. I'll edit the post !

Comment: Ho... So you want to return the whole json as receved PLUS some other additional object key/value?